# Return value based on the continous parameter python

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

Is there a nicer, more cohesive way to achieve what function `pace_points` does?
Pseudo code would be: with every x number lower of `pace` return value higher by y.

Next step pseudo code would be: with every x number lower of `pace` return value higher according to some distribution (e.g. exponential).

```
def pace_points(pace: float):
    if pace >= 6.5:
        return 0.5
    elif 6 <= pace < 6.5:
        return 1
    elif 5.5 <= pace < 6:
        return 2
    elif 5 <= pace < 5.5:
        return 3
    elif 4.5 <= pace < 5:
        return 4
    elif 4.0 <= pace < 4.5:
        return 5
    else:
        return 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following expresses you logic in a more compact form:

```
import math

def pace_points(pace):
    p = math.ceil(2*(6.5-pace))
    return 0.5 if p <= 0 else 10 if p > 5 else p
```

**FOLLOW UP**: following @DanielHao comment below, just wanted to articulate on what the code does.

- `math.ceil` returns the closest integer **higher** that the passed argument. It is different from `round`, which simply returns the closest integer. For example, math.ceil(2.3) will be 3, round(2.3) is 2. (the "sister" function to `math.ceil` is `math.floor`, which returns the closest integer lower than the passed argument.
- `math.ceil(2 * (6.5 - pace))` is a function that returns the desired values within the (0, 4.5] interval.
- The final `if...else...else` takes care of the returned value outside the interval.

Comment: It would be nicer to elaborate on the `math.ceil ....` part for uninitiated.  Upvote.